# Running a preexisting code, cannot figure out here to input parameter

Tags: c

According to the code below (obtained [here](https://projectpokemon.org/home/forums/topic/43930-mystery-gift-reverse-engineering-of-ir-protocol/); 'gifts.c'), a five-digit ID number (varies between 00000 and 65535) will yield a subset of items in Pokémon Gold, Silver and Crystal when using the Mystery Gift infrared communication. I'd like to know which items are associated with my own ID numbers, but I just cannot figure out where the IDs are supposed to go in the code. I've tried substituting pretty much every parameter for a random 12345 ID, but I keep getting error messages.

```
const char* items[] = {
    "BERRY",
    "PRZCUREBERRY",
    "MINT BERRY",
    "ICE BERRY",
    "BURNT BERRY",
    "PSNCUREBERRY",
    "GUARD SPEC",
    "X DEFENSE",
    "X ATTACK",
    "BITTER BERRY",
    "DIRE HIT",
    "X SPECIAL",
    "X ACCURACY",
    "EON MAIL",
    "MORPH MAIL",
    "MUSIC MAIL",
    "MIRACLEBERRY",
    "GOLD BERRY",
    "REVIVE",
    "GREAT BALL",
    "SUPER REPEL",
    "MAX REPEL",
    "ELIXIR",
    "ETHER",
    "WATER STONE",
    "FIRE STONE",
    "LEAF STONE",
    "THUNDERSTONE",
    "MAX ETHER",
    "MAX ELIXIR",
    "MAX REVIVE",
    "SCOPE LENS",
    "HP UP",
    "PP UP",
    "RARE CANDY",
    "BLUESKY MAIL",
    "MIRAGE MAIL"
};

const char* decorations[] = {
    "JIGGLYPUFF DOLL",
    "POLIWAG DOLL",
    "DIGLETT DOLL",
    "STARYU DOLL",
    "MAGIKARP DOLL",
    "ODDISH DOLL",
    "GENGAR DOLL",
    "SHELLDER DOLL",
    "GRIMER DOLL",
    "VOLTORB DOLL",
    "CLEFAIRY POSTER",
    "JIGGLYPUFF POSTER",
    "SUPER NES",
    "WEEDLE DOLL",
    "GEODUDE DOLL",
    "MACHOP DOLL",
    "MAGNAPLANT",
    "TROPICPLANT",
    "NES",
    "NINTENDO 64",
    "BULBASAUR DOLL",
    "SQUIRTLE DOLL",
    "PINK BED",
    "POLKADOT BED",
    "RED CARPET",
    "BLUE CARPET",
    "YELLOW CARPET",
    "GREEN CARPET",
    "JUMBOPLANT",
    "VIRTUAL BOY",
    "BIG ONIX DOLL",
    "PIKACHU POSTER",
    "BIG LAPRAS DOLL",
    "SURF PIKACHU DOLL",
    "PIKACHU BED",
    "UNOWN DOLL",
    "TENTACOOL DOLL",
};

int is_valid_item(unsigned int ID, unsigned char item) {
    if (ID > 0xFFFF) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (item >= 0x18 && item < 0x20) {
        return (item & 0x07) == ((ID>>12) & 0x07);
    } else if (item < 0x22) {
        int pos = (((item>>1)+7)&0x07) | ((item>>1)&0x08) | ((item>>2)&0x08);
        return (item & 0x01) == ((ID>>pos) & 0x01);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int is_valid_deco(unsigned int ID, unsigned char deco) {
    if (ID > 0xFFFF) {
        return 0;
    }
    return is_valid_item(((ID&0xFF)<<8)|(ID>>8), deco);
}

const char* frequency(unsigned int gift) {
    if (gift < 0x10) return "often";
    if (gift < 0x18) return "sometimes";
    if (gift < 0x22) return "rare";
    return "never";
}

int main() {
    unsigned int ID;
    while (1) {
        printf("Please enter trainer ID [00000-65535]: ");
        if (scanf("%u",&ID)<1) {
            scanf("%*s");
            printf("invalid ID\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (ID > 0xFFFF) {
            printf("invalid ID\n");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<0x22; i++) {
        printf("%17s: %s\n",items[i],is_valid_item(ID, i)?frequency(i):"no");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i=0; i<0x22; i++) {
        printf("%17s: %s\n",decorations[i],is_valid_deco(ID, i)?frequency(i):"no");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you omit the actual item lists, or did you receive the code that way? Code will fail as-is due to missing lists of items.

Comment: I did omit the items, sorry. now I've edited the question so it's the original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where the IDs are supposed to go in the code

It looks like in:

```
if (scanf("%u",&ID)<1) {
```

You can remove that whole `if` and replace it by `ID=0xsomething;` or just run the program and type the ID on the input of the program.

You could do like, with minimum changes:

```
while (1) {
    printf("Please enter trainer ID [00000-65535]: ");

    ID = 0xabcd;   // in hexadecimal for example
    ID = 12345;

    if (ID > 0xFFFF) {
        printf("invalid ID\n");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: hey! I've tried doing that, but now I get this error: prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:115:6: error: invalid suffix "x" on integer constant
   ID=0x'12345' {
      ^~
prog.c:115:8: warning: character constant too long for its type
   ID=0x'12345' {
        ^~~~~~~
prog.c:115:8: error: expected ‘;’ before '\x32333435'

Comment: don't put quotes around the number. The range is 0x0000 to 0xFFFF. If you don't know hex numbers just enter as decimal: `12345`

Comment: tried using the hexadecimal equivalent on the input box and it worked. thank you both!